# Is it possible to disable Windows 10 Action Center using an Electron Kiosk

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, electron

Windows 10 has an 'action center' which is a drawer on the right hand side of the desktop that displays notifications. I am using Electron in order to set up a touch screen kiosk on Windows 10. Is it possible to disable the action center drawer using Electron?

Here is my Electron main process code (main.js). There is an external JSON config file which contains the URL to load.

```
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')

const configFile = path.join(__dirname, "config.json")
const configJSONString = fs.readFileSync(configFile, "utf8")
const config = JSON.parse(configJSONString)

app.on('ready', () => {

  let win = new BrowserWindow({
      kiosk: true,
      autoHideMenuBar: true
    })

  // debug
  // win.webContents.openDevTools();

  win.loadURL(config.urlLocation.location)

  win.webContents.on('will-navigate', (e, url) => {
    if(url.indexOf(config.urlLocation.base) !== 0) {
    e.preventDefault();
    }
  })

  win.webContents.on('new-window', (e, url) => {
  // console.log('prevent new window creation');
    e.preventDefault();
  })

  win.on('closed', () => {
    win = null;
    })
})

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
 app.quit();
})
```

This code runs fine and kiosks the site as planned, with the exception of the Action Center still accessible by swiping left at the right-hand side of the screen.